# Another way to rewrite a code percent with this symbol >

Tags: r

Hello I want a similar code as this

```
C4 <- dfList$C4

summary(C4 %>% filter(exam == "S1" & do==2012 & grade ) %>% select(grade))
```

I mean I want to re-write that the same with simpler way.With not using %>%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
summary(subset(C4, exam == 'S1' & do == 2012 & grade, select = grade))
```

---

Or if the OP meant `|>` in `base R` (`R 4.1.0`)

```
C4 |>
   subset(exam == 'S1' & do == 2012 & grade, select = grade) |>
   summary()
```

Comment: it worked man. It says 13 minutes I need to accept it